# I'm looking for the NLab page on particle species

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, vector-bundles, principal-bundles, physics

This is just a reference request.

I came across an NLab page on particle species described as certain vector bundles. But I can't seem to find it again when I searched recently.

If someone can point out the correct page that would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: At the nLab page for species, a couple of links might be relevant: ["From finite sets to Feynman diagrams"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-56478-9_3) by Baez and Dolan (2001) and ["Combinatorial species and cluster expansions"](http://iitp.ru/upload/content/347/Dobr_Conf_2009_Proceedings.pdf#page=46) by Faris (2010)